# PowerApps: Display Calculated Value from Sharepoint List on Submission

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, powerapps

I am using a PowerApp Form to fill a SharePoint list. The Form is to create a score for a request based on a weighted average calculation. I have the field in the SharePoint list setup with the formual. I would like this to display on my PowerApps on submission of the form.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe your needs in more detail? For example, provide the renderings you want to achieve, etc.